# Separating Complex Function into Real and Imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to reduce $c\ln(z^2-a^2)+2k\pi c  $ where $c\ \in\ {Z}$ and $a>0$ and $c$ is real into its real and complex parts. I am a little stuck on how to approach separating the $ln$. I only want a hint, I want to be able to solve it on my own but an idea of where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$, then compute $z^2$, and subtract $a^2$ from its real part, then re-write $z^2-a^2$ using polar coordinates, as $re^{it}$, and apply the properties of the logarithm.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this. So doing what you said I get $c\ln(i2xy+(x^2-y^2-a^2))+2k\pi c$. I don't see how i can get it to a form where I can apply properties of the logarithm.

Comment: You weren't taught how to re-write a complex number in [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) ?

Comment: I was. You simply let $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$. I did this and plugged it in, resulting in $cln(i(2r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))+(r^2cos(\theta)^2-r^2sin(\theta)^2-a^2))$. This could then be written as $cln(r^2\exp(2i\theta)-a^2)$. But from this point I don't see how you can use properties of logarithm.

Comment: Re-write the whole $z^2-a^2$ in polar form, not just $z^2$... :-)

Comment: So, I should write it as $cln(r^2\exp(2i\theta)+|a|^2\exp(2i\theta))+i2k\pi c$ which reduces down to simply $cln(r^2-|a|^2)+i(2\theta+2k\theta c)$, right?

Comment: $r=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-a^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan\dfrac{2xy}{x^2-y^2-a^2}$